# Solutions for Recording Google Protocol Buffer Messages

Tags: protocol-buffers

My project is using protobufs for our data types. We need to be able to record our data so it can be played back later. Our use case is to recreate the event or to reprocess the same data but with new algorithms and check for improvements.

As data is flowing through our system it is all protobufs. These are easily serilized to a byte array which could be recorded to files or maybe as blobs in a database. Playback would simply mean reading the byte array and converting back to a protobuf, then sending it off into our software again.

**Are there any existing technologies used for recording protobufs?**

Even though the initial use case is very simple, eventually the solution will get more complex. It will probably need to:

- Farm out recording to multiple hosts to keep up with the input data rate
- Allow querying to find out how much data exists during a specific time period
- Play back only those data records where some field has a specific value
- Save the data for long term storage, e.g. never delete a record but instead move it to a tape backup

I think the above is best accomplished using a database which stores some subset of meta data along with the protobuf byte array itself. Before I go reinventing the wheel, I would like opinions on anything that exists already that might do this job.

Comment: if youare on unix the simplest solution is to just capture the packet stream using tcpdump.

Comment: protobuf messages are just BLOBs; you can trivially store BLOBs in most-any store. The filter is more complicated; to filter data, you'd need to deserialize, which means you'd need to know the type...

Comment: Recording via tcpdump would work but is not really extensible for the future. I was hoping there was some sort of protobuf database that could extract some meta data automatically.  Doesn't look like there is. I will start inventing my wheel shortly.